Impala multiple values in where clause complex type map
I am having a table
id  | result
Int | map<string, string>

Id  | result
1   | {”street”:”abc”, ”phone”:”123”}
2   | {”country”:”def”, ”phone”:”456”}
3   | {”street”:”abc”, ”zipCode”:”726”}
4   | {”street”:”abc”, ”phone”:”123”}
5   | {”street”:”fgh”, ”phone”:”123”}

I would like to get records with street=abc and phone=123
I wrote the query like below:
select id, r
from table, table.result r
where r.key=’street’ and r.value=’abc’
and r.key=’phone’ and r.value=’123’

The result is empty
